# Trigger Picture in Picture in new activity instead of current

Tags: android, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I'm on activity A.
I want to go to activity B, and minimize A to Pip.

I've tried :
enterPictureInPictureMode()
startActivity(B)

but the result is A minimized and then change to B, without any activity on full screenMode.

How i achieve this?